# MongoClient.connect() and DiscordClient.on() behaves differently every time I re-run my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

In my attempt to create a discord bot, I have created a very simple code to connect to MongoDB atlas, and then connect to DiscordJs.

However I'm facing wierd problems every time I **re-run my code**:

1. The connections takes random times to connect. Sometimes mongo connects instantly, and some times after 30secs. Same can be told about the Discord JS connection
2. Sometimes the connection doesnt work at all (either mongo fails or discord fails, I have given network access in atlas, so I dont think that's the issue)

This makes it extremely hard for me to debug code, as each time I have to wait a lot of time for it finally tell me 'unable to connect' :(

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, as no one else on the net seems to have this problem :(

Here is my code snippet :)

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const connectionURL = config.connectionURL;

console.log('Starting up Mongo Client...');
MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((dbclient) => {
        console.log('Estabished connection with MongoDB...\n');

        console.log('Starting up Discord Client...');
        client.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('Estabished connection with Discord...');
            console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!\n`);

            const baseFile = 'command-base.js';
            const commandBase = require(`./commands/${baseFile}`);

            const readCommands = (dir) => {
                const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));
                for (const file of files) {
                    const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
                    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                        readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
                    } else if (file !== baseFile) {
                        const options = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
                        commandBase(dbclient, client, options);
                    }
                }
            };

            readCommands('commands');

        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database...');
        return;
    });

client.login(config.token);
```

**//edit1//**

This is type 1 error that I get when MongoDB does not connect

```
Starting up Mongo Client...
Unable to connect to the database... MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/vrishinvv/JavaScript/discord-bot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'discord-bot-shard-00-00.ynyjy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'discord-bot-shard-00-02.ynyjy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'discord-bot-shard-00-01.ynyjy.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure what the issue is, but the place you put the log saying that you are starting up a discord client, is not where you start up the client, subscribing to the ready event is not the cause of it's trigger, which is why i assume a part of the issue is you improperly subscribing to events/badly asynchronously starting up discord, could you give us the rest of the code? so we can at least try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I have edited the code to contain the full code, but I think it will be insecure to reveal my config.token and config.connectionURL in a public domain. Moreover, I was aware that, it was not where the discord client started, but kept it there to give me an idea as to how long it takes for the .on() function to connect to the discord servers. I guess you are right about the badly writen async part, any tips on how to go about it :(